# Java maze solving and reinforcement learning

Tags: java, maze

I'm writing code to automate simulate the actions of both Theseus and the Minoutaur as shown in this logic game; http://www.logicmazes.com/theseus.html

For each maze I provide it with the positions of the maze, and which positions are available eg from position 0 the next states are 1,2 or stay on 0. I run a QLearning instantiation which calculates the best path for theseus to escape the maze *assuming no minotaur*. then the minotaur is introduced. Theseus makes his first move towards the exit and is inevitably caught, resulting in reweighting of the best path. using maze 3 in the game as a test, this approach led to theseus moving up and down on the middle line indefinatly as this was the only moves that didnt get it killed.

As per a suggestion recieved here within the last few days i adjusted my code to consider state to be both the position of thesesus and the minotaur at a given time. when theseus would move the state would be added to a list of "visited states".By comparing the state resulting from the suggested move to the list of visited states, I am able to ensure that theseus would not make a move that would result in a previous state.

The problem is i need to be able to revisit in some cases. Eg using maze 3 as example and minotaur moving 2x for every theseus move.
Theseus move 4 -> 5, state added(t5, m1). mino move 1->5. Theseus caught, reset. 4-> 5 is a bad move so theseus moves 4->3, mino catches on his turn. now both(t5, m1) and (t3 m1) are on the visited list

what happens is all possible states from the initial state get added to the dont visit list, meaning that my code loops indefinitly and cannot provide a solution.

```
public void move()
{
    int randomness =10;
    State tempState = new State();
    boolean rejectMove = true;
    int keepCurrent = currentPosition;
    int keepMinotaur = minotaurPosition;

    previousPosition = currentPosition;
    do
    {
        minotaurPosition = keepMinotaur;
        currentPosition = keepCurrent;
        rejectMove = false;

        if (states.size() > 10)
        {
            states.clear();
        }


        if(this.policy(currentPosition) == this.minotaurPosition )
        {
            randomness = 100;
        }

        if(Math.random()*100 <= randomness)
        {
            System.out.println("Random move");
            int[] actionsFromState = actions[currentPosition];
            int max = actionsFromState.length;
            Random r = new Random();
            int s =  r.nextInt(max);    

            previousPosition = currentPosition;
            currentPosition = actions[currentPosition][s];
        }
        else
        {
            previousPosition = currentPosition;
            currentPosition = policy(currentPosition);
        }

        tempState.setAttributes(minotaurPosition, currentPosition);
        randomness = 10;    

        for(int i=0; i<states.size(); i++)
        {
            if(states.get(i).getMinotaurPosition() == tempState.getMinotaurPosition()  &&  states.get(i).theseusPosition == tempState.getTheseusPosition())
            {

                rejectMove = true;

                changeReward(100);

            }
        }

    }
    while(rejectMove == true);

    states.add(tempState);
}
```

above is the move method of theseus; showing it occasionally suggesting a random move

Comment: I'm not expecting anyone to code this for me, im just looking for ideas on how to approach this. clearly i need to be able to prevent revisitng previous states, but handling resetting when caught is the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is a discrepancy between the "never visit a state you've previously been in" approach and your "reinforcement learning" approach. When I recommended the "never visit a state you've previously been in" approach, I was making the assumption that you were using backtracking: once Theseus got caught, you would unwind the stack to the last place where he made an unforced choice, and then try a different option. (That is, I assumed you were using a simple depth-first-search of the state-space.) In that sort of approach, there's never any reason to visit a state you've previously visited.

For your "reinforcement learning" approach, where you're completely resetting the maze every time Theseus gets caught, you'll need to change that. I suppose you can change the "never visit a state you've previously been in" rule to a two-pronged rule:

- *never* visit a state you've been in during this run of the maze. (This is to prevent infinite loops.)
- *disprefer* visiting a state you've been in during a run of the maze where Theseus got caught. (This is the "learning" part: if a choice has previously worked out poorly, it should be made less often.)

Comment: Hi again :)
When i say reset, the updated scores associated with having gotten caught remain, but the positons of the agent are reset. Its not really searching the possible moves, its picking what's expected to be the best move as based on the scores from the qlearning algorithm.

Comment: re: "never visit a state you've been in during this run of the maze. (This is to prevent infinite loops.)" what happens when all possible moves have been tried? clear the list of visited states?

Comment: Hi! Re: "When i say reset, [...] the positons of the agent are reset": Yes, I understood that. :-)

Comment: If all possible moves have been tried, and you're not using backtracking, then that's the end of that run of the maze. (You obviously don't want to reinforce that; I'm not sure if you want to punish it, either, or if it's better to just let that be a neutral result.)

Comment: ok, so im not sure how best to adjust what i have so far, is there any way i can show you what i have so far?

Comment: You can certainly edit your question to include relevant code, if that will help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9285/discussion-between-confusified-and-ruakh)

Answer (score 2):

For what is worth, the simplest way to solve this problem **optimally** is to use [*ALPHA-BETA*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-beta_pruning), which is a search algorithm for deterministic two-player games (like tic-tac-toe, checkers, chess). Here's a summary of how to implement it for your case:

1. Create a class that represents the current state of the game, which
   should include: Thesesus's position, the Minoutaur's position and
   **whose turn is it**. Say you call this class `GameState`
2. Create a heuristic function that takes an instance of `GameState` as paraemter, and returns a double  that's calculated as follows:

   - Let Dt be the [Manhattan distance](http://www.improvedoutcomes.com/docs/WebSiteDocs/Clustering/Clustering_Parameters/Manhattan_Distance_Metric.htm) (number of squares) that Theseus is from the exit.
   - Let Dm be the Manhattan distance (number of squares) that the Minotaur is from Theseus.
   - Let T be 1 if it's Theseus turn and -1 if it's the Minotaur's.
   - If Dm is not zero and Dt is not zero, return Dm + (Dt/2) * T
   - If Dm is zero, return -Infinity * T
   - If Dt is zero, return Infinity * T

The heuristic function above returns the value that Wikipedia refers to as "the heuristic value of node" for a given `GameState` (node) in the pseudocode of the algorithm.

You now have all the elements to code it in Java.

Comment: I don't think that works here, since the Minotaur is not a true second player; rather, he's an element of the maze, and he follows rigid rules for how he moves. (Also, the OP is not trying to *optimally* find the optimal solution; rather, (s)he is trying to apply a reinforcement-learning approach.)